# Why does AWS give the option of revoking root user access on S3 buckets when a root user can put it back again?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For an S3 bucket, under

> Amazon S3->bucketname->Permissions

tab, you'd find the section that says **Access for your AWS account root user** where AWS gives you the option to amend root user access on the S3 bucket. Why is this special option given for S3 bucket ? Isnt the root account supposed to have all access by default? For example, you dont get the option to restrict the root user from launching an EC2 instance. More important, my question is - Why does AWS give the option of revoking root user access on S3 buckets when a root user can again put it back?

Answer (score 1):

IAM roles, Access control lists can be used to revoke access. Even root users do not have access to buckets without proper roles.